# Github workflow for pip fails because Python version is not found

Tags: python, github, pip, github-actions, version

My Github workflow fails to install Python 3.8.2 and shows the following error:

```
Run actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    python-version: 3.8.2
    token: ***
Version 3.8.2 was not found in the local cache
Error: Version 3.8.2 with arch x64 not found
The list of all available versions can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/python-versions/main/versions-manifest.json
```

If it helps, relevant parts of my workflow file is as follows:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8.2"]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
```

What am I missing? And how can I fix the error?

I tried checking the URL in the error, however it shows that there are versions existing with the `x64` architecture for darwin, linux and win32. So, I don't know if I am misunderstanding the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arose because `ubuntu-latest` is dynamic. Currently, `ubuntu-latest` points to 22.04. At least that's what I understand from [this link](https://github.com/actions/runner-images#available-images). From the cache, I see that Python v3.8.2 is supported for ubuntu 20.04 (at the latest) and not for 22.04, which was causing the fail.

Therefore, fixing the ubuntu version should help. Changing the line

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

in the workflow file to

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
```

worked! Python could be used from the cache and subsequent jobs ran.

Thanks to PforPython's answer for getting me to think in the right direction.

Comment: It's an issue with [actions/setup-python](https://github.com/actions/setup-python) that doesn't support the version you need. See https://github.com/actions/setup-python/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#python where it explains its caching. If a runner doesn't have a cached version, it downloads it from the releases of https://github.com/actions/python-versions. As an end user, you may [create an issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/new/choose) to request the inclusion of the specific version that you need.